# How to increase google cloud AI notebooks GPU memory

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have a pretty big model I'm trying to run (30 GB of ram minimum) but every time I start a new instance, I can adjust the CPU ram but not the GPU. Is there a way on Google's AI notebook service to increase the ram for a GPU?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: you can't. You might consider switching to Colab Pro that features e.g. better GPU:

> With Colab Pro you get priority access to our fastest GPUs. For
>   example, you may get access to T4 and P100 GPUs at times when
>   non-subscribers get K80s. You also get priority access to TPUs. There
>   are still usage limits in Colab Pro, though, and the types of GPUs and
>   TPUs available in Colab Pro may vary over time.
>
> In the free version of Colab there is very limited access to faster
>   GPUs, and usage limits are much lower than they are in Colab Pro.

That being said, don't count on getting best-in-class GPU just for yourself for ~10 USD / month. If you need high-memory dedicated GPU, you will likely have to resort to using a dedicated service. You should easily find services with 24 GB cards for less than 1 USD / hour.

Comment: I have colab pro already, works fine for all my projects except for this particular one it keeps crashing, unfortunately.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a [personalized](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new#create-with-options) AI Notebook and also [edit its hardware](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/manage-hardware-accelerators) after the creation of it. Please take special care if you are not hitting the [quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/troubleshooting#gpu_quota_has_been_exceeded) for GPU if you still are not able to change these settings.